# What is the difference between SAP BW\4 HANA and SAP native Hana?

Tags: hana, business-objects, sap-bw

Is S/4 HANA and BW/4 HANA are same? Also what is the difference of this with BO? If it is just reporting then why still BO?
Appreciate your help.

Comment: SAP HANA is a database system based on SQL. SAP S/4HANA and SAP BW/4 HANA are two completely different software, but with HANA in common. BO is a different solution than BW, BO has more sophisticated queries. Probably they are interfaced together more or less since SAP purchased BO a few years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S/4 is ERP solution, BW is Data Warehousing framework, HANA is a DBMS that have an ability to run application platform inside it (XS Advanced). S/4 and BW/4 both run on NetWeaver platform and they both use HANA DBMS underneath. But their purposes are different. Since NetWeaver is an app platform you can install BW/4 and S/4 on the same system, but it is another question. SAP BO is another application platform that is used for reporting (WebI, Crystal Reports, AFO) and data integration (Data Services) apps of BO package.

Answer (score 1):

**What is SAP BW?**
The production of reporting and data warehousing solutions with the help of business intelligence and analytical approach is called SAP NetWeaver Business Warehouse.

SAP BW is another term used for it. It is one of the best and most powerful Enterprise Data Warehouse applications that provide authentic and complete business solutions and come with complete business packages such as business intelligence and optimized for the R / 3 environment for SAP. However, compatibility is not limited only to the R / 3 environment as it is flexible with any data warehouse enterprise.

**What is SAP HANA?**
SAP HANA is an in-memory database.

Read the article [**What is Sap HANA**](https://sapprofession.com/sap-bw-vs-sap-bw-hana/) for more details.